# What does it mean for non planar surfaces to intersect orthogonally?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, orthogonality, quadrics

A question in Do Carmo's differential geometry book states:

Given:

$$x^2+ y^2 + z^2 = ax$$
$$x^2+ y^2 + z^2 = by$$
$$x^2+ y^2 + z^2 = cz$$

The question is to show that those are regular surfaces (which is fairly straightfrward) But then it asks to show that they intersect orthogonally.

I am not sure what kind of quadrics (conicoids) are, but they are definitely not planes. What does it mean for a quadric (surface) to intersect "orthogonally"?

Comment: Show that their respective normal vectors (at points of intersection) are orthogonal.

Comment: so find the curves of intersection, then show that the normals at each point in the curve of intersection are orthogonal to those of the other surface?

Comment: Yes, the two appropriate normals at such points should be orthogonal.

Comment: makes sense, that is pretty straightforward then